# Physical storage differences in Azure Storage tiers

Tags: azure

I think I have a good understanding of Azure Storage Tiers (Hot, Cool, Cold and Archive) from the cost, SLA and best practices points of view. What I can't find any info on is how these tiers are physically stored and why the SLAs are different. I do know that Archive is tape or similar. It's Hot, Cool and Cold that I'm asking about.

From what I have found, it is not SSD vs HD. (Premium is using SSD drives.)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft doesn't disclose this because it's not important. They could very easily store "Cold" files on expensive SSDs (for some period of time) if some hyper-optimized-for-profit algorithm says so.

What's important is the *minimum gurantees* you get from each Tier - which doesn't preclude MS exceeding those minimums (e.g. by storing Cold files on fast SSDs).

---

By analogy, it's [like CPU binning](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/glossary-binning-definition,5892.html): if you're a customer looking for a new CPU the only way to *guarantee* that you'll get a top-tier chip is by paying through [the nose for one](https://www.newegg.com/intel-xeon-platinum-8180-lga-3647/p/N82E16819117904?Item=9SIAH59J5D5583), even though the mid-tier chips are identical and you *might* get lucky, Intel/AMD aren't going to guarantee that a mid-tier chip meets the specs of the high-end binned parts.

---

Also (speaking anecdotally), considering the *sheer speed* at which Azure Blob Storage is able to change the storage tier of my blobs between Hot, Cool, and Cold, there's *no way* that they're physically moving the data between SSD and spinning-rust drives exactly at that point - my observation is the data gets moved around asynchronously, even though they update the billing data for my storage instantly (this also explains why there's a [30/90 day minimum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/access-tiers-overview#summary-of-access-tier-options) for some tiers).

Comment: Not the answer I was really looking for, but maybe "Microsoft doesn't disclose this" is as close as I'll get.

Comment: @MikeSmith-MCT even if they did, the info will be obsolete in a few years as the entire storage industry shifts to SSDs for _everything_ now because they’re so cheap overall (especially lifespan and running costs)